# Gatsby - overwriting images

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm making a site using gatsby CMS, but now I ran into a problem that I have no idea how to solve.
I have project pages that I create from markdown files in gatsby-node. It works as it should, creates pages with proper slugs and so on. Now, the problem is that I have created two project pages, both of them have images that are called the same - but reside in different folders:
In `projects/foo.md`

```
---
templateKey: project-page
headerImage: /img/projects/foo/Header.jpg 
---
```

Then in `projects/bar.md`

```
---
templateKey: project-page
headerImage: /img/projects/bar/Header.jpg 
---
```

Then in the template I call

```
<div className="hero"
  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${data.headerImage.publicURL})` }}
>
```

It works well for `foo` project. But for `bar` one it still shows the same image as in `foo`, for both being `style='background-image: url("/static/Header-920eee5baf94303a7a172f4ccef3b60b.jpg");'`. I have no idea what is going on.

If it helps, the content of my `gatsby-node.js` is:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const path = require('path')
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')
const { fmImagesToRelative } = require('gatsby-remark-relative-images')

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              templateKey
              headerImage {
                publicURL
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach(e => console.error(e.toString()))
      return Promise.reject(result.errors)
    }

    const projects = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges

    projects.forEach(edge => {
      const id = edge.node.id
      createPage({
        path: edge.node.fields.slug,
        tags: edge.node.frontmatter.tags,
        component: path.resolve(
          `src/templates/${String(edge.node.frontmatter.templateKey)}.jsx`
        ),
        // additional data can be passed via context
        context: {
          data: edge.node.frontmatter
        },
      })
    })

  })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  fmImagesToRelative(node) // convert image paths for gatsby images

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```